# How to convert this JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, json

I am using an API that returns me the result JSON formatted like this:

```
{
"undefined":{  
  "theresult":{  
     "back_1s":{  
        "consumed":1115287.58,
        "min_cons":28789,
        "max_cons":1086498.58,
        "totalobjs":12683,
        "totalproces":4298
     },
     "back_10s":{  
        "consumed":1115287.58,
        "min_cons":28789,
        "max_cons":1086498.58,
        "totalobjs":12683,
        "totalproces":4298
     }
  }
}
}
```

The first thing I did was creating a C# object that has 5 properties for each of the JSON's values.
Then I de-serialized the JSON string into an array of this new object.

However I have no idea what `back_1s` is, and what it will represent in C#,not to mention `theresult` and the `undefined`.

I just see no way for me to de-serialize it without help.

This is how I de-serialize in C#

```
List<NEWOBJECT> gooddata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NEWOBJECT>>(jsonstring);
```

EDIT #1:

I am getting this error when I deserialize in C#

```
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'mvcAndrew.Controllers.NEWOBJECT[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Comment: what values from this json are you looking for ?

Comment: theresult can be a dictionary of your class with 5 properties..

Comment: I want the 5 values `consumed`..etc and want to know if it is `back_10s` or `back_1s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest ist to generate the C# Classes from JSON:
http://json2csharp.com/

If you deserialize it use the generated RootObject class (or rename the class) that should do the trick.

This will generate two classes for Back1s / Back10s - you can still use only one class (delete the other one) and edit the "Theresult" class corresponding (for example, I renamed Back1s to BackClass and deleted the Back10s class)

```
public class Theresult
{
    public BackClass back_1s { get; set; }
    public BackClass back_10s { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Newtonsoft.json.

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJsonHere);
var recList = files.SelectToken("$..theresult").ToList();
foreach (JObject item in recList.Children())
        {
            string values = item["consumed"].ToString();
            // You can get other values here
        }
```

Comment: Oh good to know....that would be my preferred choice, instead of creating tons of classes

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a class structure same as your return object may be kind of

```
 public class backDetails
 {
    public double consumed { get; set; }
    public double min_cons { get; set; }
    public double max_cons { get; set; }
    public double totalobjs { get; set; }
    public double totalproces { get; set; }
 }

public class TheResult
{
    public backDetails back_1s { get; set; }
    public backDetails back_10s { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public TheResult theresult { get; set; }
}
```

Then this will work

```
List<MyClass> gooddata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(jsonstring);
```